# MediaElement.js - how can I set the default image that is displayed?

Tags: mediaelement.js

Is there a way to set the initial player to one of the following:

1. To a specific image file, then switch to the video when play is selected/fired
2. Set the initial image to one of the frames within the video

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Inside the video tag specify an attribute **poster="path/to/image"**.
   and assign a value to an image.